# GitLab API - How to list all files in subfolder

Tags: c#, gitlab, httpclient, gitlab-api

I'm having quite the time trying to get this seemingly simplistic line of code to work using C#.  Trying to get a list of all my files in my repo.
File structure below:

```
MyRepo
-directory_01
--myFile_01.jpg
--myFile_02.jpg
```

This line of code lists all my directories and works great:

`var streamTask = client.GetStringAsync(https://myURL/api/v4/projects/myRepo/repository/tree?private_token=myToken"`

According to the api, to get my files only I should use `files/:file_path` attribute or `archive.<file extension>` to get my files.

```
//Get all .jpg files
var streamTask = client.GetStringAsync(https://myURL/api/v4/projects/myRepo/repository/archive.jpg?private_token=myToken"

OR
//Get one file
var streamTask = client.GetStringAsync(https://myURL/api/v4/projects/myRepo/repository/files/directory_01%2FmyFile_01%2Ejpg?private_token=myToken"

//result: 404
```

Comment: What you want is to actually download these files?

Comment: No, I'd like to just get a list of the files in the repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this issue, here's a way to do this:

```
    // Get list of files***********
    string treeUri = $"{project}tree?private_token={projectToken}&ref=master";
    string treeData = await client.GetStringAsync(treeUri);
    
    List<AssetEntry> json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<AssetEntry>>(treeData);
    Console.WriteLine("FILE LIST:\n");

    foreach (var item in json)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.name + " " );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you this API you also need to pass the `branch name`

Change

```
var streamTask = client.GetStringAsync(https://myURL/api/v4/projects/myRepo/repository/files/directory_01%2FmyFile_01%2Ejpg?private_token=myToken"
```

To

```
var streamTask = client.GetStringAsync(https://myURL/api/v4/projects/myRepo/repository/files/directory_01%2FmyFile_01%2Ejpg?private_token=myToken&ref=<branch_name>"
```

Comment: Thank you for this response.  I tried adding the branch name, but it just returns a blank result.  No error at least

Comment: Maybe you need to await since you are fetching async?